# Ajax page loader

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make a website for a radio station and they want the users to browse the site without interrupting the music stream.

I've found this code below but when browsing to another page on the site the header also gets loaded again which means I end up with two headers. I have tried to find solutions but cannot find any.

I'm using webflow so the code must be only in javascript or jquery.

```
let main = document.querySelector('body > main');

   window.addEventListener('popstate', function (e) {
       requestPage(e.state, false);
   });

   function requestPage (url, push) {
       let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
           if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
               main.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
               attachLinkClickHandlers(main);

               document.title = xhr.getResponseHeader('Page-Title');
       

    if (push)
                   history.pushState(url, document.title, url);

               document.body.classList.remove('loading');
           }
       };

       xhr.open('get', url, true);
       xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Only', 1);
       xhr.send();

       document.body.classList.add('loading');
   }

   function attachLinkClickHandlers (parent) {
       let links = parent.querySelectorAll('a:not([href^="http"])');

       [].forEach.call(links, function (link) {
           link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
               requestPage(link.href, true);

               e.preventDefault();
               return false;
           });
       });
   }

   attachLinkClickHandlers(document);

   history.replaceState(location.href, document.title, location.href);
```

Comment: What's being returned by your ajax call? If you're returning the full HTML, headers included, then they will be loaded. You could check server-side to see if it's an ajax call, then return a different version of the page, one without headers.

Comment: Why the `jQuery` tag? I removed it.